# How to setHighlightedTextColor @ NSAttributedString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a custom UITableViewCell which uses a NSAttributedString. I want it to change color when the cell is selected. How can I make the NSAttributedString have the same behavior as a UILabel with highlightedTextColor set?

I have tried to change the color at the functions setSelected and setHighlighted of the cell, but it seems that they are called to late (on touchUpInside instead of touchDown)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using smth like:
NSAttributedString string;
 [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
when your cell is selected?

Comment: I can change the text color, but I don't realize that the cell has been selected until the touchUp

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath - no luck either?

Comment: I am trying to do it within a UITableViewCell class, which unfortunatelly does not have that method

Comment: yes, I know. what I meant was, if you have a UITableViewCell, you probably have a UITableView? on didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can get the cell and then modify its content. I know it's not what you want, but perhaps it could work

Comment: It probably would work, but I would have to change it in too many places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel subclass solution

```
@implementation CustomLabelHighlighted
{
    NSAttributedString *savedAttributedString;
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (!highlighted) 
    {
       [super setAttributedText:savedAttributedString];
       return;
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString *highAttributedString = [savedAttributedString mutableCopy];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, highAttributedString.string.length);
    [highAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:self.highlightedTextColor range:range];
    [super setAttributedText:highAttributedString];
}

- (void)setAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)attributedText
{
    [super setAttributedText:attributedText];
    savedAttributedString = attributedText;
}

@end
```

Comment: not a bullet proof solution but convenient when you need to handle very simple use cases

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's pretty simple to detect selection/highlighting and change colors depending on it. The important methods are:

```
-(void)setHighlighted:animated:
-(void)setSelected:animated:
```

note that when overriding you have to use the methods with `animated:`, otherwise it won't work.

When you want to change only the color, the simplest solution is to let the color to be set on the label and not on the string. Note that the attributed string is still inheriting all the properties of the `UILabel`.